# script not working with my xml to string

Tags: php, xml, string

first of all sorry for my poor english :)  i have a question about this script. i found this script into an old framework and i wanna use it for my friend but i can't make this script working without the whole framework.

string.php

```
<?php
class StringResource{
    private $string = array();
    public function StringResource($path){
        global $lang;
        if($lang == null){
            $file = $path . 'strings.xml';
            if(file_exists($file))
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
        }else{
            $file = $path . 'strings_'.$lang.'.xml';
            if(file_exists($file)){
                $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
            }else{
                $file = $path . 'strings.xml';
                if(file_exists($file))
                    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
            }
        }

        if($xml){
            foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
                if($child->getName() == 'string'){
                    $attribute = $child->attributes();
                    $key = (String) $attribute['name'];
                    $this->string[$key] = (String) $child;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function Get($key){
        return $this->string[$key];
    }
}
```

i know i could use gettext etc but my friend knowledge is very low so editing one file is the best for him.

strings.xml
here a sample of my xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <strings>
          <string name="menu1">Menu 1 name</string>
          <string name="menu2">menu 2 name</string>
            ....
```

and when i wanna use them i use {{ST:menu1}} so i don't need to deal with echo.
so what is missing for this script to work correctly? is the get key function act like a replace?

Answer (score 2):

You create the object with:

```
$sr = new StringResource("/path/to/directory/");
```

where the XML data is in `/path/to/directory/strings.xml`.

Then you can get a string with:

```
$menu1 = $sr->Get("menu1");
```

BTW, using the name of the class as the method name is an obsolete way to write a constructor in PHP. The modern way is to name it `__construct`.

Comment: yes sorry the object is already created in another file. 
the problem is i separate my html from my php so i cannot use php code in a tpl file

Comment: There's nothing in the question about `.tpl` files. I don't know what that is, I guess it's some kind of template framework? If you're using a framework, you should include those details in the question and add a tag for it, then the people who know about it will see the question.

Comment: tpl is an php extention similar to html but without any php code. 
about the framework i have no idea because all comment as been removed. i have buy that script on codecanyon and the author used a old framework and used to remove all comment from the framework.